# KML - show multiple points on map

Tags: kml

I would like to show multiple points on google map with KML file. I try below sample but only the first point show on map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251 -122.08223,37.42228</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

I expect above sample:
1. Show 2 points on map
2. Show each point with a dot (currently it's a icon and too big).

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the icon, that is a separate question, there is nothing in your KML to do that, see the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#style) for how to style placemarks and examples of styling `Point` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Point` can only have one set of coordinates. Multiple points in the `<coordinates>` element are used for `LineString` (lines) and `Polygon` paths. You need multiple `<Point>` elements if you want multiple markers.

Updated KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.08223,37.42228</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet (using geoxml3 to parse the KML):**

```js
var kmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Placemark><Point><coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><Point><coordinates>-122.08223,37.42228</coordinates></Point></Placemark></kml>';
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 42,
      lng: -70
    }
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    infoWindow: infowindow,
    singleInfoWindow: true
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlString);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas">
```